# Algebraic curves from (quiver) gauge theory

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, research-level, topological-field-theory

I'm interested in algebraic curves one can associate to gauge or string theories. Examples involve Seiberg-Witten curves or family of A-polynomials which define holomorphic Lagrangian submanifolds for $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ Chern-Simons theory or alternatively mirror Calabi-Yau manifolds to resolved conifold.

I'm wondering if something like this has been done for quiver gauge theories, for simplicity with symmetric quivers (or even general)? Are there any algebraic curves one can associate to quivers or quiver gauge theories that have some interpretations? It would be really good if those curves were Riemann surfaces.
I've heard of Nakajima quiver varieties but I don't know if they are algebraic curves.